# How to display a message while there is no data in Axios using reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am working on a reactjs project, and nodejs i have 3 routers to count the user comments, likes, asked questions, and I need to show to her/his profile the results if they asked a question, or if they comment on someone post, in case the user is completely new I want to show just (0)

how can I do it?
this is code for the server-side

```
// user likes counter
router.get("/likescounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const likesCounter = await Likes.count({
    where: { UserId: id },
  });
  res.json(likesCounter);
  console.log("Likes counter in like", likesCounter);
});
```

and this is the client-code

```
    axios
  .get(`${targetServer}/like/likescounter/${id}`)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data) {
      setLikesCounts(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

and finally, this is where I render the result in the UI

```
         <span className="text-gray-700">
                {likedCount}
         </span>
```

also, this is how the UI looks like:
[image]

any sugesstion please?

Comment: What is the server response when the user is completely new?

Comment: @RyanLe this is the response from the sever-side:
Likes counter in like 0

Comment: Isn't it a console.log from the server? May I know what print in this? `console.log(res.data);`

Comment: And how is the UI suppose to show if it's returned from a new user?

Comment: console.log(res.data); it doesn't return any response while there is no data, but if there is likes, it returns

Comment: i don't want to show anything if a user is new, just display (0)

Comment: I put a new answer to that, does it fit your needs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236512/discussion-between-ryan-le-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Base on information from the comment section, I would presume that you want to show (0) if the data is falsy (undefined, null)**

So you would need to make a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

**First, make sure your state initialize like this:**

```
const [likedCount, setLikedCount] = useState(0);
```

**Then update your jsx:**

```
<span className="text-gray-700">
      {likedCount ?? '0'}
</span>
```

**Or [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) if you also want to show `0` if it returns a falsy value**

```
<span className="text-gray-700">
      {likedCount || '0'}
</span>
```

---

**An alternative for old browsers or no babel configured project:**

```
<span className="text-gray-700">
      {likedCount ? likedCount : '0'}
</span>
```

if `likedCount` === undefined or null it will show `0`

Comment: i got this error message:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (441:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 25
|     }
>   }, likedCount ?? 0), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("span", {
|     className: "text-sm text-gray-500",
|     __self: this,

Comment: Oh, so it's probably not accepting the latest operator. I will update the answer

Comment: HUUM, yeah with the || operator it doesn't give an error, but it did not display anything.

Comment: Hey, please try the last one

Comment: Glad it helped!